# mysql timestamp difference in timestamp

Tags: mysql, timestamp

I want to get the difference between timestamps, in timestamp format, using only MySQL and not using a programming language. Also not in seconds, hours, date, months or years. 
as an example.

```
timestamp1->2012-05-21 15:31:11
timestamp2->2012-05-21 15:32:11
```

I want to get the result in timestamp format.

So the result should be

```
result->0000-00-00 00:01:00
```

Answer (score 6):

Use MySQL's [`TIMEDIFF()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_timediff) function:

> [`TIMEDIFF()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_timediff) returns ***`expr1`*** – ***`expr2`*** expressed as a time value. ***`expr1`*** and ***`expr2`*** are time or date-and-time expressions, but both must be of the same type.
>
> The result returned by `TIMEDIFF()` is limited to the range allowed for [`TIME`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/time.html) values. Alternatively, you can use either of the functions [`TIMESTAMPDIFF()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_timestampdiff) and [`UNIX_TIMESTAMP()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_unix-timestamp), both of which return integers.
>
> ```
> mysql> SELECT TIMEDIFF('2000:01:01 00:00:00',
>     ->                 '2000:01:01 00:00:00.000001');
>         -> '-00:00:00.000001'
> mysql> SELECT TIMEDIFF('2008-12-31 23:59:59.000001',
>     ->                 '2008-12-30 01:01:01.000002');
>         -> '46:58:57.999999'
> ```

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer. But in that your method the result is not in timestamp format. I want the  answer as a timestamp

Comment: @KasunMalith: How could one do that? For example, how would 792 hours (33 days) be returned? Is that `0000-01-03` or `0000-01-02`? Or something else (February, for example, contains 28 or 29 days depending on the year).  How would a negative difference be returned?